# Ordenar por columna String en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una columna de una tabla de tipo *string* que tiene los siguientes valores:

```
1/2024  
2/2024  
1/2023  
2/2023  
3/2023  
....  
816/2023  
817/2023  
818/2023
```

Quiero hacer una `select` que me devuelva los valores de la tabla ordenados por ese campo de manera descendente, de tal manera que le resultado sea el siguiente:

```
2/2024  
1/2024  
818/2023  
817/2023  
816/2023  
.....  
3/2023  
2/2023  
1/2023
```

He probado con expresiones regulares y varias formas más pero no doy con la tecla adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes separar la columna por la barra y luego ordenar primero por año y luego por el numero que va por delante:

```
SELECT columna
FROM tabla
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(columna, '/', -1) AS UNSIGNED) DESC, 
         CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(columna, '/', 1) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

Comment: Casí. Tienes que convertir los substrings en números, porque 2 < 10, pero '2' > '10'.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner creo que ahora si funcionara como tu dices.